# display all rows of a table after a join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I want to display all the rows of Table A after joining elements from matching column from Table B

Table A

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| FirstName | LastName |    Date    |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| Tia       | Carrera  | 1975-09-18 |
| Nikki     | Taylor   | 1972-03-04 |
| Yamila    | Diaz     | 1970-03-05 |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Table B

```
+-----------+------------+
|    code   | Date       |
+-----------+------------+
| 1234      | 1975-09-18 |
| 56789     | 1972-03-04 |
| 54856     | 1968-07-14 |
+-----------+------------+
```

everything I found online looks like

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| FirstName | LastName |    Date    |    code   |
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| Tia       | Carrera  | 1975-09-18 | 1234      |
| Nikki     | Taylor   | 1972-03-04 | 56789     |
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

**but this is the result that I want**

```
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| FirstName | LastName |    Date    |    code   |
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| Tia       | Carrera  | 1975-09-18 | 1234      |
| Nikki     | Taylor   | 1972-03-04 | 56789     |
| Yamila    | Diaz     | 1970-03-05 |           |
+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: use a LEFT JOIN instead of a INNER JOIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `left join`:

```
select a.*, b.code
from a left join
     b
     on a.date = b.date;
```